# Append quint16/unsigned short to QByteArray quickly

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

In my project I'm working with QByteArrays appending data to them as the program goes. Most of the time, a simple `quint8` gets appended just fine using `QByteArray::append()`. But when a `quint16` gets appended, only 1 byte gets appended instead of 2.

```
QByteArray ba = QByteArray::fromHex("010203");
quint number(300);//300 in hex is 012c

ba.append(number);//What should be appended instead of just number?

//the current incorrect result is
ba.toHex() == "0102032c"

//the desired result is
ba.toHex() == "010203012c"
```

I've already tried this, but it just inserts the value as a string (4 bytes):

```
ba.append(QByteArray::number(number, 16));
```

What should I append to the QByteArray so both bytes of "number" get appended instead of just one byte? Also, the fastest method possible is preferred since this program needs to have great performance times. So absolutely no converting to QStrings.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What endianness do you expect when appending a `quint16`?

Comment: I believe big endian. It should be 012c getting appended

Comment: Reading the doc I see no trace of a `QByteArray.append(quint)`...

Comment: Why not just use a `QList<quint16>`?

Comment: Because the QByteArray isn't just a bunch of quint16's as stated in the post.

Comment: But a `quint16` can hold a `quint8`, so a single `QList<quint16>` can hold all of your data.  Maybe you should explain what you're using your `QByteArray` for once you've finished populating it - because as your question stands, it just looks like you're trying to put `quint16` into a `quint8` and wondering why it's not working.

Comment: I'm taking elements (sometimes bytes, sometimes ints, or shorts, strings, floats, doubles, etc...) from a QByteArray containing a huge file, and editing them, then putting them into a new QByteArray that is organized differently. I'm sticking with QByteArrays. There are even Byte and Int arrays WITHIN the QByteArray itself.

Comment: I was more or less asking how to turn quint16 into two seperate quint8's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On its own, `QByteArray` only supports appending bytes; to append a big-endian representation of fixed-size integer types you can build your own `operator<<` (or what you prefer) overloads using the appropriate bit shifts:

```
QByteArray &operator<<(QByteArray &l, quint8 r)
{
    l.append(r);
    return l;
}

QByteArray &operator<<(QByteArray &l, quint16 r)
{
    return l<<quint8(r>>8)<<quint8(r);
}

QByteArray &operator<<(QByteArray &l, quint32 r)
{
    return l<<quint16(r>>16)<<quint16(r);
}
```

This allows you to write code like:

```
QByteArray b;
b<<quint16(300);     // appends 0x01 0x2c
b<<quint8(4);        // appends 0x04
b<<quint16(4);       // appends 0x00 0x04
b<<quint32(123456);  // appends 0x00 0x01 0xe2 0x40
b<<quint8(1)<<quin16(2)<<quint32(3); // appends 0x01 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03
```

You should probably avoid writing

```
QByteArray b;
b<<1;
```

because in theory the output depends on the size of the current platform integer (although AFAIK on all platforms supported by Qt `int` is 32 bit).

Comment: Hate to ask this, but how about going backwards? So from a QByteArray containing "012c" to a qint16? I already tried ba.mid(3,2).toUShort(0,16) however that won't work since it's not looking at the binary data.

Comment: To read a big-endian value to an integer the normal way is "for each byte read left shift the target by 8 and OR the read byte into the target". That is more easily done with an actual stream that keeps track of the read position.

Comment: QByteArray b;
b<<quint16(300);
no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘QByteArray’ and ‘quint16’ {aka ‘short unsigned int’}) Qt 6.7

Comment: @АндрейТернити did you add the overloads I wrote above?

Comment: works very good! Qt 6.7

Answer (score 0):

This is my little-endian version

```
typedef union{
    uint16_t u16;
    uint8_t u8s[2];
}uint8_16_t;

typedef union{
    uint32_t u32;
    uint16_t u16s[2];
}uint16_32_t;

QByteArray &operator<<(QByteArray &l, quint8 r){
    l.append(r);
    return l;
}

QByteArray &operator<<(QByteArray &l, quint16 r){
    const uint8_16_t v= {.u16=r}; //v means val
    return l<<v.u8s[0]<<v.u8s[1];
}

QByteArray &operator<<(QByteArray &l, quint32 r){
    const uint16_32_t v= {.u32=r};
    return l<<v.u16s[0]<<v.u16s[1];
}
```

How to use?

```
quint8 myu8= 1;
quint16 myu16= 0xEEFF;
quint32 myu32= 0xAABBCCDD;
QByteArray arr;
arr << myu8 << myu16 << myu32;
qDebug().noquote().nospace() << "0x" << arr.toHex().toUpper();
```

Out:
0x01FFEEDDCCBBAA